# Finding $\int\frac{6x^2 + 4x }{e^x + 2} dx$

Tags: calculus

> Find the following integral:
>   $$\int\frac{6x^2 + 4x }{e^x + 2} dx$$

My turn :

Let $$u = 6x^2 + 4x , dv= \frac{dx}{e^x +2}$$
$$du = 12x + 4 dx , v = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(e^{-x} + 2$$
$$I =( 6x^2 + 4x)( -\frac{1}{2}\ln(e^{-x} + 2) + \int  (-\frac{1}{2}\ln(e^{-x} + 2) (12x + 4) dx$$
But I could not do the last integral.

Comment: Try integration by parts

Comment: *Mathematica* gives $$-2 (3 x+1) \text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{e^x}{2}\right)+6
   \text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{e^x}{2}\right)+x \left(x^2+x+x \log (8)-(3 x+2) \log
   \left(e^x+2\right)+\log (4)\right)$$

Comment: Do you that it has no anti-derivative by the standard formulas @David G.Stork

Comment: I have already dine it but i got this integral $$\int\frac{6x^2 +4x }{4e^x +2} dx $$ which looks similar yo the original integral @Anand

Comment: There is no closed form that does not involve special functions.